# How to create a custom UIButton in code and use it in a xib?

Tags: ios, xib, nib, uicontrol

I have a class `MyButton : UIButton` which inherits from UIButton. I do a bunch of things in the initWithFrame (the only constructor)of MyButton say like setting the backgroundcolor.

Now I want to use this MyButton in my xib. so that I dont keep setting these properties again and again for all my buttons. I have also set the Custom Class to MyButton in the Identity Inspector for the button in the xib.

Nothing still reflects the properties I set in the xib. This could have been easily done if it was in the code.

My question is, 
1) What gets called when you create button thru a xib (like you call initWithFrame when you programmatically create a button) ?

2) How do I get it to see the properties I set in the MyButton ? Is moving out of xib and doing it programatically the only way ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typically with `initWithCoder:`
2. You can use the identity inspector in Interface Builder to set values using the keypath of the attributes.  In this example, you can change the `CALayer` properties of the view:

[image]

Comment: For point number 2, I will have to keep doing for every MyButton I create. That destroys the point of having a custom control.

Comment: btw your initWithCoder comment was helpful. I could define the properties in there ! Thanks !! Marking as answer

Comment: one more thing - initWithCoder will not pick up the values defined in the Key Path. The values does get picked up in AwakeFromNib though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set it in your `xib` file. For that:

1. Select the button in the `xib` file.
2. Click the Identity Inspector button.
3. Type the name of your custom class(`MyButton` for your case) in the Class field.

Now your button will be with the Type `MyButton` class.

**EDIT**

Check [Apple's documentation on Adding a Custom Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-general/CustomObject.html). This will give you more idea.

Comment: As I said it doesn't pick up the properties I set in the base class. I want to use the MyButton custom control which has some properties set directly from the Xib.